# Is client side routing recommended along with the server side routing provided angular-universal

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, isomorphic-javascript, angular-universal

I'm just starting out with Angular Universal and completely new to 'isomorphic' javascript.

I'm a little confused as to how to have a logical routing system, are you meant to build out angular universal as a typical node rest api? Or is it literally just meant to serve client side code instantly, and retrieve data from an outside source/rest api?

As to take the angular universal starter kit for example it starts with these routes;

```
app.get('/', ngApp);
app.get('/about', ngApp);
app.get('/about/*', ngApp);
app.get('/home', ngApp);
app.get('/home/*', ngApp);
```

is it then logical to include a node/express/mongo api along side this to get/post data? ie;

```
const bearRoutes = require('./routes/bear')
app.use('/', bearRoutes)
```

If it is, would you then use a hashing strategy in order to differentiate the URLS?

Would there be a noticeable performance difference between serving data on an angular2 app using universal from an external api compared to having everything hosted together?

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I'm a little confused as to how to have a logical routing system, are you meant to build out angular universal as a typical node rest api?

Yes. `angular-universal` takes that philosophy. You build the routes on server side because everything is built out server side.

> is it then logical to include a node/express/mongo api along side this to get/post data?

Yes for your data services.
e.g. [Hello World example with github services makes API requests](https://github.com/angular/universal/blob/master/examples/hello-world/src/app/github/services/github.service.ts)
No for `app.use` because this is essentially your Node REST server.

> If it is, would you then use a hashing strategy in order to differentiate the URLS?

First thing is anything after `#` in the URL is not going to be seen by the server side. But the problem you describe is about naming the URLs and whether or not to differentiate between the URLs that serves the angular compiled/rendered HTML content vs the data/API services.

Answer is Yes. This is for your own good in managing your server routes. For example if your routes are

```
app.get('/', ngApp);
app.get('/about', ngApp);
app.get('/about/*', ngApp);
app.get('/home', ngApp);
app.get('/home/*', ngApp);
```

you could just add

```
app.get('/api/profile', serverAPIAppOrprofileJSON);
```

> Would there be a noticeable performance difference between serving data on an angular2 app using universal from an external api compared to having everything hosted together?

Think about a scenario where a small section of your page changes due to certain user interaction and that needs you to bring some data. You may want to just update this section instead of rendering the whole page. So performance will be better in this situation.

Comment: Okay so I should create/host a node REST server seperately? As before I have read when building something like a blog application for example, it is advisable to have the Node REST server serve the html directly through hbs/jade etc then have the admin section as a seperate SPA. Where as in the case of angular Universal, it sounds like you will have the node rest server, the angular universal server as the client side consuming the node rest server and then you could still have the admin section as a seperate SPA or perhaps even as another universal set up?

Comment: Regardless of where the rendering occurs API server being separate is desirable as the application grows. API services may have other consumers and may have separate deployment and development lifecycle.